# How to make system search for .keystore file in project directory, by default it checks for .keystore file in C:\Users?

Tags: java, ant, build, keystore, keytool

I am using ANT to build a war file for my project which uses applets. I have created a keystore file in the project directory, but on build up system checks for the .keystore file in C:\Users, how can I make the system search for the keystore file in project directory?

On building the project using ANT in command prompt, i am getting the following error:

```
D:\Gopakumar\Score>ant

Buildfile: build.xml

prepare:

cleartomcat:

 clear-remote:
     [delete] Deleting directory D:\Gopakumar\Score Remote API\build\classpath

incremental-remote:
       [echo] BUILDING REMOTE API
       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Gopakumar\Score Remote API\build\classpath
       [javac] Compiling 52 source files to D:\Gopakumar\PBL ScoreCard Remote API\build\classpath
       [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
       [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

clean-remote:

clear-pc:
     [delete] Deleting directory D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath
     [delete] Deleting directory D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\dist

incremental-pc:
     [echo] BUILDING PERFORMANCE CHART APPLET
     [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath
     [copy] Copying 57 files to D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath

    [javac] Compiling 37 source files to D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath

[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

[copy] Copying 35 files to D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart App
 let\build\classpath

[unzip] Expanding: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\lib\hessian-3.0.13.jar into D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath
 [unzip] Expanding: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\lib\composite-1.0.jar into D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath

[unzip] Expanding: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\lib\morph-1.0.jar into D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath

[unzip] Expanding: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\lib\commons-logging-api.jar into D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath

[unzip] Expanding: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\lib\jgraph.jar into D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\build\classpath 
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\dist

[jar] Building jar: D:\Gopakumar\PBL ScoreCard Performance Chart Applet\dist\performancechartedit.jar

[signjar] Signing JAR: D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\dist\performancechartedit.jar to D:\Gopakumar\Score Performance Chart Applet\dist\performancechartedit.jar as csi
[signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\bimal\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)

[signjar] Enter Passphrase for keystore:

BUILD FAILED

D:\Gopakumar\Score\build.xml:556: The following error occurred while executing this line:

D:\Gopakumar\Score\build.xml:147: jarsigner returned: 1
```

The system checks for the .keystore file in "C:\Users\bimal.keystore" but actually the file is in "D:\Gopakumar\PBL ScoreCard". How can I change the path so that the system will look for the .keystore file in "D:\Gopakumar\PBL ScoreCard" ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the signjar ant task [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html), it appears there is a "keystore" attribute which can be used to specify keystore location.